# How to extract a part of a csv file, from tuple to a string?

Tags: python, csv, text-processing

I want to extract a specific part out of a .csv file. But when I call `str(extractOut)` on the piece I grep'ed before I get a strange output. The content of the .csv file looks like this:

```
example,example,TTT,1234,12345678,0
...
```

To extract the third part ("TTT") I use grep:

```
extract = subprocess.Popen("grep -oP 'TTT,\K[^,]*(?=,)' example.csv | sed -n 1p", shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
extractOut = extract.communicate()
```

Then as described before I use `str()` to convert the output to a string.
But when I print it out I get the following:

```
(´TTT\n´, ´´)
```

I only want the clear text "TTT", maybe I could use a workaround and just cut the 2 first characters and the eight last.
How could I achieve to get only the clear text ?

Comment: why don't you use python csv  reader? https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: What's your expected output? You don't need a grep ommand.

Comment: `str(tuple).replace("\n", " ")` and write a function to do that to any non-letter character. I can write a function for it if you need

Answer (score 1):

That is one ugly way to extract things from csv, why not use existing tools that allow for much more elegant solution?

For example:

```
import csv

with open('example.csv') as csvfile:
    data_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in data_reader:
        print(row[2])
```

Will print TTT

Comment: Ah almost forgot that my bad. I guess I'm still a newbie. One question I have more than one line in my cvs file. How do I specify the line and the row to print out ?

Comment: @Nroh you will have to count the lines processed and run your collection only when the counter is at number you want. You cannot just jump to specific line as this would require whole CSV to be loaded into memory, which with larger files would be very silly thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools for this, namely: `read.csv()`.  Here I duplicated your three rows, and saved them to `example.csv`:

```
> tmp <- read.csv("~/Desktop/example.csv", header = FALSE)
> tmp
       V1      V2  V3   V4       V5 V6
1 example example TTT 1234 12345678  0
2 example example TTT 1234 12345678  0
3 example example TTT 1234 12345678  0
> tmp$V3
[1] TTT TTT TTT
Levels: TTT
```